# How to uploade images to disk in asp.net core 2 , razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

i'm beginner in asp.net framework, but i really encouraged to learn and apply it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start

i followed it and everything is ok and i passed to add new models, tables.

suppose we have the Movie model which is :

```
public class Movie
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

and below is the code of Create process:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        _context.Movie.Add(Movie);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
```

Below is a section from the from :

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Movie.Price" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Movie.Price" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Movie.Price" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

Now i want to add a new field to the form to upload the "Cover image", so the user can browse and select the cover image for the movie to upload it in the same form.

my questions are :

- i think to store the file name in the DB, so each movie has a column
  "CoverImage", then i can use it to display or delete. is this good
  approach ?
- what is the best place to store the files ? in "wwwroot" or another
  folder or doesn't matter ?
- what is the best or latest method to upload the image ? what should i add in the three sections of codes above? i did a search and i found many approaches and methods, but i need to know
  from you as experts in asp.net what is the best approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To store the image path in the table, you need to first add a property to your entity class so that it will create a column in your table.

```
public class Movie
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string ImageName  { set;get;}   // This is the new property
}
```

Now to receive the file from the UI , you need to add a new property to your PageModel class of type `IFormFile`

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public Movie Movie { set; get; }

    [BindProperty]
    public IFormFile Image { set; get; }
}
```

Now in your form, add an input element of type `file`. Make sure your form tag has an `enctype` attribute and it's value is set to `multipart/form-data`

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>

    <input type="text" placeholder="Title" asp-for="Movie.Title"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Genre" asp-for="Movie.Genre" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Price" asp-for="Movie.Price"/>
    <input type="file"  asp-for="Image"/>

    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Now in your `OnPost` method, you can read the `Image` property value of the page model and save it to the disk. In asp.net core, the `wwwroot` directory is a special directory to keep the static assets. So you may keep the images under that. I would create a sub directory called `uploads` inside `wwwroot`.

To get the path to the `wwwroot` directory, you can use `IHostingEnvironment`. So inject that to your page model class.

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
     private readonly YourDbContext context;
     private readonly IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment;
     public CreateModel(YourDbContext context,IHostingEnvironment environment)
     {
        this.hostingEnvironment = environment;
        this.context=context;
     }
    //Your existing code for properties goes here
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return Page();

        if (this.Image != null)
        {
            var fileName = GetUniqueName(this.Image.FileName); 
            var uploads = Path.Combine(hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "uploads");
            var filePath = Path.Combine(uploads,fileName);
            this.Image.CopyTo(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
            this.Movie.ImageName = fileName; // Set the file name
        }
        context.Movie.Add(this.Movie);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToPage("MovieList");
    }
    private string GetUniqueName(string fileName)
    {
        fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
        return Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName)
               + "_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 4)
               + Path.GetExtension(fileName);
    }
}
```

This will save the file to `wwwroot/uploads` and store the image name in the `ImageName` property of the `Movie` record we are saving. So when you want to display the image, read the record, and use the `ImageName` property and create the url. (Ex : '`yourSiteName/uploads/aaa_9521.jpg`, where the `aaa_9521.jpg` will come from your Movie records `ImageName` property value)

For example, in another page where your page model has a `Movies` property which is a collection of `Movie` entities, you can do this

```
<table>    
    @foreach (Movie m in Model.Movies)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@m.Title</td>
            <td>@m.Price</td>
            <td>
                <img src="~/uploads/@m.ImageName"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: really thanks, worked well, just a last question, if i want to add a function to make some validation on the image , from your point of view, where is the best please to put such functions ? the validation function and GetUniqueName  (Helper functions ) for example ?